# python argparse how to continue the program after the [-h] command?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to write an interpreter. And facing a problem.

```
while True:
    cmd = input('>>>')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', help='foo')
    parser.parse_args(cmd.split())
```

when I type the [-h] command, it exits the program.

```
>>>-h
usage: test.py [-h] [-f F]

optional arguments:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit
-f F        foo
```

Now, I just want that 'show this help message' but not 'exit'. So how can I do, please?

Comment: well -h is for help command it gives you the help summary  and it is supposed to work like this

Comment: Maybe you should give the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) module a try instead. Using `argparse` for command line parsing does not sound ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by erasing the predefined help command and adding an own:

```
import argparse

while True:
    cmd = input('>>>')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='store_true',
            help = 'show this help message')
    parser.add_argument('-f', help='foo')
    args = parser.parse_args(cmd.split())
    if args.help:
        parser.print_help()
```

Comment: yes, some well known tools are able to print help _and_ do the job at the same time. Great answer.